# Debugging intermittent problem in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I would like to run a program (that requires arguments) repetitively in gdb under linux.  It takes about a minute to run and it fails once every 30 or so times through.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`gdb --eval-command=run --args executable-file [inferior-arguments ...]` where `executable-file` is your executable and `[inferior-arguments ...]` is the list of arguments it takes will run your program once under gdb.

Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to get gdb to quit when the program exits successfully. You could use `--batch`, but that doesn't let you do interactive debugging. It will at least give you a backtrace though. And you could use a `--command` file to dump everything you care about in `--batch` mode.